# Writing a systemd process that checks it's status with `systemctl`?

Tags: systemd, container

I have a third party (Microsoft) that bundles a product (SQL Server 2017) as a `systemd` task. Everything pretty much works, but their bundling actually checks if the service is running with `checkrunninginstance.sh` which has,

```
systemctl status mssql-server > /dev/null 2>&1
exit $?
```

This is problematic because [I can't find a way for the container itself to either,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457819/3285)

- integrate with the host's copy of systemd, from a chroot
- run as systemd using nspawn

Is it advised for `systemd` tasks to use `systemd` themselves? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please try to clarify? If you're running something in a container, you might want to consider using [`machinectl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html) to run it. It's compatible with `systemd-nspawn` but it registers it as a "machine." Also note that you can ask `systemctl` on the *host* to tell you about the status of services inside a *machine* (registered by `machinectl`) by passing `systemctl` the [`-M` argument](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-M).

Comment: You might enjoy [this article](http://0pointer.net/blog/systemd-for-administrators-part-xxi.html) about container integration with systemd. Good luck!